# Spring 3 MVC Validation is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to use simple form validation. When I enter wrong data, method hasErrors always return false. Could you please help find the problem?

Part from Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/measure", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateMeasure(@Valid @ModelAttribute("measure") Measure measure, BindingResult result){
    System.out.println("result has errors: " + result.hasErrors());
    System.out.println("updated measure: " + measure.getWeight());
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "measure";
    }
    return "redirect:measure";
}
```

Model:

```
public class Measure {

@Range(min = 1, max = 70)
private int weight;

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}}
```

Part of servlet-config.xml:

```xml
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.kidstat"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```xml
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API and JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>kidstatServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>kidstatServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Have you tried @Size(min=1 ,max=7)?

Comment: @Darya Golub pls post the spring context xml file also, make sure you have this in your xml `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

Comment: @ankur-singhal , <mvc:annotation-driven/> is in servlet-config.xml above

Comment: @DinoTw yes, I tried Size, Min, NotNull, NotEmpty - result is the same

Comment: @DaryaGolub post your `web.xml` also

Comment: @ankur-singhal question updated with web.xml

Answer (score 0):

do you have something like this in your controller?

```
@ModelAttribute("measure")
public Measure ConstrutMeasure() {

    return new Measure();
}
```

also just a side note in the line

```
return "redirect:measure";
```

You probably want to redirect to the measuer page again with a message if verything goes well so you can do it like this

```
return "redirect:/measure.htlm?@@=##
```

then you can access ## in the view via

```
<c:if test="@@ eq ##"> </c:if>
```

and do what ever you want to do with it